# Is Homomorphism equivalent to Field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, ring-homomorphism

I am recently reading a book on Field Theory. Here is a section on field extension
[image]
I feel that this is wrong because it assumes that $\theta$ is a bijection, which is not homomorphism. (Unless it define $\theta$ to be injective)

Am I correct? I just want to assure myself.

Comment: It's implicitly assumed the reader will fill the details. Anyway, once you've checked it is a homomorphism and it's not $0$, it's necessarily injective.

Comment: This argument does not *assume* that $\theta$ is a bijection, it is something that is easily *proved*.

Comment: @Bernard Presumably, the author does not allow the $0$-map as a homomorphism, as it will not actually be one of unital rings. That said, wow. That is a terrible way to formulate these things

Comment: I skipped the first section of the book, and I still treat 0 as a homomorphism. :)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Exactly my thoughts...this is the worst I've read for a long time. Would be interested in knowing the source.

Comment: wait a moment, I will find the source

Comment: @J.S.Bach The map $\;\theta\;$ , not being the zero map (which would be suspicious between unitary rings among many mathematicians, anyway) is injective, and it is onto its image, obviously. That the image within $\;K\;$ can be made into a field which will be almost trivially isomorphic with $\;E\;$ is something most authors leave for the reader to complete.